# Keyboard shortcut to go to an interface from the class that implements it in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, interface

In VS Code, I have `controller-a.ts` open. I want open the interface's file (`interface-controller.ts`), which includes definition of the `execute` method.

Imagine that the `controller-a.ts`, `controller-b.ts`, & `interface-controller.ts` have many dozens of lines each.

When on `execute()` in `controller-a.ts`, is there a way to quickly navigate to the interface that this class implements (via keyboard or mouse) without scrolling up to the top of the class to see the name of the implemented interface, manually opening the file, then going down to the execute method? I'm open to VS Code extensions.

**Things I've Tried:**

- <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> the implementation of the `execute` method (on macOS)
- `Go To Definition`
- `Go To Implementations`
- `Go To References`

*Result*: Opens a "peek" with 3 references. The references listed are `controller-a.ts`, `controller-b.ts`, and `interface-controller.ts` but `controller-a.ts` is the file automatically selected in the "peek", which is the file that I'm already in.

**Other Things I've Tried:**

- `Go To Type Definition`

*Result*: Goes to `lib.es2018.promise.d.ts`

**Other Things I've Tried:**

- `Go To Source Definition`

*Result*: Stays in `controller-a.ts`

**./interface-controller.ts**

```
export interface IController {
  execute(): Promise<void>
}
```

**./controller-a.ts**

```
import { IController } from "./interface-controller";

class ControllerA implements IController {
  public async execute() {
    // stuff
  }
}
```

**./controller-b.ts**

```
import { IController } from "./interface-controller";

class ControllerB implements IController {
  public async execute() {
    // stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Best Alternative So Far**

Example: `Find All Implementations` on `execute` in `controller-a.ts`

*Result*: Shows a list of the `controller-a.ts` & `interface-controller.ts` in the sidebar and automatically focuses it.

- <kbd>down arrow</kbd> to `interface-controller.ts`
- <kbd>right arrow</kbd> to expand `interface-controller.ts` in the list
- <kbd>down arrow</kbd> to select the `execute` method
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which takes you straight to the `execute` method on the controller